# Unable to install express-graphql

Tags: node.js, npm, graphql, express-graphql

**I'm trying to install `express-graphql` but getting this error. Please, help!**

```
npm install --save express-graphql 
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: rest-api@1.0.0
npm ERR! Found: graphql@16.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/graphql
npm ERR!   graphql@"^16.2.0" from the root project 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer graphql@"^14.7.0 || ^15.3.0" from express-graphql@0.12.0
npm ERR! node_modules/express-graphql
npm ERR!   express-graphql@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Comment: Same error. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I am facing a similar problem.

Answer (score 17):

Delete the full initialized project then run the following:

```
npm init -y
npm install express express-graphql
npm install graphql
```

You should install `express-graphql` before `graphql`.

Answer (score 5):

Uninstall `graphql` module if it's present. Then install both of them with one command:

```
npm install graphql express-graphql
```

Answer (score 3):

I generated my app using:

```
npx express-generator <projectName>
```

and to solve the issue, I just did:

```
npm un express graphql
```

which where modules that I had already installed and then ran:

```
npm i express-graphql graphql express
```

in that order worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

1. Delete `package.json`, `package-lock.json`, & `node_modules`.
2. Initialize `npm` again.
3. Now, install `express-graphql` with `npm` at first (install before any other package in the app).

These steps solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try deleting `package-lock.json`? It may help as per the [github issue](https://github.com/graphql/express-graphql/issues/584).

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the other answers, first remove `graphql` via:

```
npm remove graphql
```

Now install `express-graphql` with this command:

```
npm install express-graphql
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Install in this order:

```
npm install express-graphql graphql express
```

Answer (score 0):

Install `express-graphql` before installing `express`.

Comment: ? The OP just failed to install express-graphql, so how he will install before something else ?

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install express-graphql --save --force
```

works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted `package-lock.json` and ran

```
npm install express-graphql graphql --save
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I installed `graphql` then `express-graphql`, then `npm i express --force`

Answer (score 0):

If you try to install `express-graphql` after `graphql`, it creates the conflict and that errors you see in the console.
According to GraphQL spec, you should use the following modules installation order:

```
npm install express express-graphql graphql --save
```

To fix the issues, you should:

1. Remove `graphql`
2. Install `express-graphql`
3. Install `graphql`

Answer (score 0):

STEP 1: Delete `package.json`, `package-lock.json`, `node_modules` and start again.

STEP 2: `npm install express express-graphql graphql --save`

Apparently installing packages in that order works. Command is copied from `GraphQL` docs.
https://graphql.org/graphql-js/running-an-express-graphql-server/

Answer (score 0):

install `express-graphql` with `yarn`

1. install yarn `npm install --global yarn`
2. install dependencie`yarn add express-graphql`
3. `be happy!`